# Sub-Query in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have query like this in jpql

```
select new com.example.CustomGroup(m.id, m.title, (select count(w.id) from MessageGroup x join x.messages w where w.readers.id <> ?1) ) 
from MessageGroup m join m.members u where u.id = ?1
```

but not work, i know jpa 2 support sub query in select but cant find any refrence to how use it

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? Do you get an exception? How does the SQL look like that is generated by Hibernate? How would you do that query in SQL?

Comment: Start by telling people which JPA provider you are using. And is this the ACTUAL query, or the query is something "like" this (hence the "like" word in your statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the JPA 2.2 specification, paragraph 4.6.16:

> Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause.[66]
>
> [66] Subqueries are restricted to the WHERE and HAVING clauses in this release. Support for subqueries in the FROM clause will be considered in a later release of this specification.