# How to convert the query to HQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have this query in SQL Server that consumes two parameters `startDate` and `endDate`.

Could you help me to convert it to HQL in order to make it database independent?

```
SELECT LeaseTable.CarMake, AVG(LeaseTable.LeaseHours)
FROM
(SELECT lease.carmake, 
    DATEDIFF(HH, case when lease.startDate <@startdate then @startdate else lease.startDate end, dateadd(DD, 1 ,case when lease.endDate > @endDate then @endDate else lease.endDate end)) as LeaseHours
    FROM lease
where 
    lease.startDate <= @endDate AND lease.endDate >= @startdate) as LeaseTable
GROUP BY LeaseTable.carMake
```

Comment: subquery is only supported in WHERE and HAVING in JPQL https://stackoverflow.com/a/52492077/2190218

Answer (score 0):

As JPQL does not support sub-query, you will have to tweak the query to get the result

You can write the query like this

```
String query = "SELECT l.carMake ,"
         + "         AVG("
         + "           DATEDIFF("
         + "             HH,"
         + "             CASE WHEN lease.startDate <:startdate THEN :startdate ELSE lease.startDate end,"
         + "             dateadd(DD, 1 ,case WHEN lease.endDate > :endDate THEN :endDate ELSE lease.endDate end)"
         + "            )"
         + "         )"
         + " FROM lease l"
         + " WHERE l.startDate <= :endDate AND l.endDate >= :startdate"
         + " GROUP BY  l.carMake; ";
```

Basically, take out the date_diff function out of the sub-query into AVG function